# What happens to memory that wasn't freed in a kernel module after unloading?

Tags: kernel, memory, kernel-modules, memory-leaks

Suppose I called `kmalloc` and didn't free that memory before `rmmod` was called on the module, what happens to that memory? Is it a memory leak and it is completely unusable until restart, or does the kernel free that memory automatically?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't be freed until explicitly done. Memory allocated with `kmalloc()` needs to be freed using `kfree()`. That piece of memory stays till the system is on.

> [...] didn't free that memory before `rmmod` was called on the module [...]

When you do `rmmod`, `module_exit()` will be executed where you can free the memory incase when memory has to freed when module is unloaded. for example.

```
x() {
 z = kmalloc(...)
}
y() {
  kfree(z)
}
module_init(x)
module_exit(y)
```